# UIWebView, quote characters with Arial font not showing up correctly

Tags: iphone

I have some .html with the font defined as:

`<font color="white" face="Arial">`

I have no other style applied to my

tag.  In it, when I display data like:

`<b> “Software” </b>`

or

`<b>“Software”</b>`

they both display characters I do not want in the UIWebView.  It looks like this on a black background:

[image]

How do I avoid that?  If I don't use `font face="arial"`, it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an encoding issue. Make sure you use the same encoding everywhere. UTF8 is probably the best choice.

You can put a line

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
```

in your html to tell `UIWebView` about the encoding.

To be precise, `â€œ` is what you get when you take the `UTF-8` encoding of `“`, and interpret it as `ISO-8859-1`. So your data is encoded in `UTF-8`, which is good, and you just need to set the content type to `UTF-8` instead of `ISO-8859-1` (e.g. using the `<meta>` tag above)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn’t generally use the curly quote characters themselves—character encodings will always mess you up somehow. No idea why it works correctly when you don’t use Arial (though that suggests a great idea: don’t use Arial), but your best bet is to use the HTML entities `&ldquo;` and `&rdquo;` instead.

Comment: Although I agree about the use of entities vs non-ascii chars, this can and should be solved in the proper way, by setting the right encoding. Just replacing quotes by `&ldquo;` etc doesn't actually solve the underlying issue, which will often come back at some point.